# Quantile cuts despite duplicates

Tags: r

I have a dataset with > 900,000 rows with many duplicates:

```
> sum(duplicated(df$colB))
[1] 904515
```

So when I try to quantile cut into ten equally large subsets, I get an error

```
> df$colC <- cut(df$colB, quantile(df$colB,c(0:10)/10), labels=FALSE,
+                   include.lowest=TRUE)
Error in cut.default(df$colB, quantile(df$colB,  : 
  'breaks' are not unique
```

Using `unique(quantile(df$colB,c(0:10)/10))` doesn't give equally sized subsets. There must be an easy solution to make quantile cuts which also considers the number of rows, in addition to the values in `colB`. Starting a loop sequence would probably take forever as I have a high number of rows. Any ideas?

Dummy dataset:

```
set.seed(10)
B <- round(runif(100, 0, 0.4), digits=2)  # gives 63 duplicates
df$colB <- B
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a neater solution than this, but this will do it:

```
df$colC <- ceiling((1:nrow(df))*10/nrow(df))[rank(df$colB, ties.method = 'first')]
table(df$colC)
#> 
#>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
#> 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Comment: Excellent! @pseudospin Do you know a way to filter the elements in the data frame before ranking, ie: rank only values in `df$colB > 2`?

Comment: With large quantities of data like this, I wouldn;t do it in base R, definitely one for `data.table`. I.e. `setDT(df)[colB > 2, colC := ceiling((1:.N)*10/.N)[rank(colB, ties.method = 'first')]]`

Answer (score 1):

It might be hard to imagine, but there must be a range of values in `df$colB` that is invariant, so `quantile` returns two (or more) of a single value.

A contrived example:

```r
set.seed(42)
vec <- c(rep(10,20),sample(100,size=80,))
brks <- quantile(vec, (0:10)/10)
brks
#    0%   10%   20%   30%   40%   50%   60%   70%   80%   90%  100% 
#   2.0  10.0  10.0  14.7  25.6  36.5  47.4  58.9  72.4  88.1 100.0
```

The `cut` function requires that there be no repeated values in its `breaks=` arguments. It should be informative to look at just the quantiles of your function to confirm this.

One way around this is to use `.bincode`, which does not enforce unique breaks.

```r
cut(vec, brks, include.lowest = TRUE)
# Error in cut.default(vec, brks, include.lowest = TRUE) : 
#   'breaks' are not unique

.bincode(vec, brks, include.lowest = TRUE)
#   [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  7  8  4  9  4
#  [26] 10  6  4  8 10  6  4  5  1  6  5  5  1  5  9  7  6 10  5  6  4  4  9  1  9
#  [51]  8 10  1  7 10  9  8  1  8  1  7  9  7  4  8  7  6  1  6  9  5  8  6 10  6
#  [76]  9  1  5  3 10  6  5  9  4  5  7 10  7  8  9  4  5  7  3  8  4 10  7  8 10
```

(Note that there is no "2" in the return values with this data, because `brks[2]` is the same as `brks[3]`, so appears to be ignored.)

One side-effect of this is that you don't get the `factor` labels by default, which might be useful.

```r
labels <- sprintf("(%0.01f-%0.01f]", brks[-10], brks[-1])
substr(labels[1], 1, 1) <- "["
labels
#  [1] "[2.0-10.0]"    "(10.0-10.0]"   "(10.0-14.7]"   "(14.7-25.6]"  
#  [5] "(25.6-36.5]"   "(36.5-47.4]"   "(47.4-58.9]"   "(58.9-72.4]"  
#  [9] "(72.4-88.1]"   "(100.0-100.0]"

head(labels[ .bincode(vec, brks, include.lowest = TRUE) ])
# [1] "[2.0-10.0]" "[2.0-10.0]" "[2.0-10.0]" "[2.0-10.0]" "[2.0-10.0]" "[2.0-10.0]"
```

(Where the use of `%0.01f` is where you may want to customize this assumption.)